# how to convert an array of data into merged html table using nodejs

Tags: node.js, html-table

First I get an array of data by `SELECT`ing from mysql database. The array looks like:

```
[
{client:A, day:mon, product_name:product1},
{client:A, day:mon, product_name:product2},
{client:A, day:tue, product_name:product3},
{client:B, day:mon, product_name:product4},
]
```

With the array I made a html table that looks like:

```
client | day | product_name
---------------------------
A      | mon | product_1
---------------------------
A      | mon | product_2
---------------------------
A      | tue | product_3
---------------------------
B      | mon | product_4
```

But instead, I would like to make a merged table like below. How would I do this? I know I have to use rowspan. But since this is a large array, **I am looking for some simple algorithm or npm module that does this for me.**`(array)=>(html code)`

```
client | day | product_name
---------------------------
       | mon | product_1
             --------------
A      |     | product_2
       --------------------
       | tue | product_3
---------------------------
B      | mon | product_4
```

Comment: If you don't want to use rowspan you can create a function that generates tables, and use the same function for your main table, and use it again when you reach product_1, product_2 parent cell, that means you'll need to format your array accordingly ... there isn't a short way, not one that i'm aware of though

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `rowspan` property of `<td>` to make a cell span multiple rows vertically.

Since you didn't provide any sample code, here's a quick generic example based on your placeholder data:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>client</th>
        <th>day</th>
        <th>product_name</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="3">A</td>
        <td rowspan="2">mon</td>
        <td>product_1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>product_2</td>
    </tr>
    <!-- And so on -->
</table>
```

Of course you'd want to apply the `rowspan` values dynamically based on how many rows you need, but how to do that would depend on how you're construcing the table HTML.

Comment: Sorry I didnt specify the problem sufficiently. I corrected my question